# .addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Quero adicionar um evento quando ocorre a rolagem da página, porém ocorre o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).addEventListener is not a function
> ```

Segue código:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body').addEventListener('scroll', change)

function change() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('primeiro').classList.add('destaque')
 }
```

Como posso corrigir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já dito na [resposta do Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420056/112052), [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) e [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) retornam um array de elementos. Mas se quiser, há a alternativa de usar [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) e [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

No caso específico da [*tag* `body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body), só pode haver uma dela no documento HTML, então não tem porque usar `getElementsByTagName`, você pode usar simplesmente `document.querySelector('body')`, no qual já será possível chamar `addEventListener`. Se bem que no caso do `body`, você pode obtê-lo diretamente com `document.body`, que o resultado é o mesmo:

```js
console.log(document.body === document.querySelector('body')); // true
```

Como alternativa à `getElementsByClassName`, você pode usar `document.querySelectorAll('.primeiro')` para buscar todos os elementos que possuem a classe `primeiro` (e note que há um ponto antes de "primeiro", para indicar que é uma classe - diferente de `getElementsByClassName`, que não precisa do ponto).

Então o trecho referente ao `body` ficaria assim:

```
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', change);
```

---

Mas na verdade, o `scroll` no `body` não funciona como você espera ([veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654838)). Para que um *scroll* na tela dispare o evento, adicione-o diretamente no `document`:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', change);

function change() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.primeiro')
        // para cada elemento encontrado, adicione a classe "destaque"
        .forEach(e => e.classList.add('destaque'));
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 200px;
}

.destaque {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p class="primeiro">Primeiro</p>
    <p>Segundo</p>
    <p class="primeiro">Outro Primeiro</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByTagName` retorna um array de objetos, para usar o `addEventListener` é preciso ser um único objeto, por isso acontece esse erro.

Como é um array, você pode pegar o primeiro elemento e atachar o evento, por exemplo:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('scroll', change);
```

Ou poderia ainda associar a cada elemento (o `body` só vai ter um no `document`, mas se fosse outro elemento como um `div`, isso funciona bem) e atachar o evento:

```
var elementos = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
for(i=0;i<elementos.length;i++) {
    elementos[i]..addEventListener('scroll', change);
}
```